# Swift custom animations progress

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, ios-animations

I'm looking for some 3rd party or code snippets for implementation of the custom animations like this one: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nwmkBgHYUFGR_rrn9aM6S1CrSLpOb6Jb (take a look at the top bar of progress animations)

I am not strong in animations in iOS and this one looks to me like a complex task with all these bounces etc.

Could you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this https://github.com/yenbekbay/AYStepperView ?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to play with this one and others mentioned below.

Comment: you can create your own, create custom view tap gesture and use CALayer class its required so much calculation if number of points are not fixed( in my case i was passing number and based on that the number of calayer was adding and just fill the each CALayer object based on the user tap, you can user stoker color and a all lot of freedom if you are creating own custom slider. If time is not a constrain you should create your own and share :-) PS: you can always take help from the projects mentions here and build your own :-)

Comment: Thank you @IraniyaNaynesh . Once I'll write my own, but currently I'm looking for existing solution due to time constraints :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a lot of such 3d party libraries on cocoacontrols. For example:

1) https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/absteppedprogressbar

2) https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cmsteppedprogressbar

3) https://github.com/yenbekbay/AYStepperView